# Roth IRA vs Individual Brokerage Approach

Tags: roth-ira, brokerage

How does investment approach change between a Roth IRA vs. an individual brokerage account? If your individual account is focused on long term investments over several years, would it be reasonable to just have the same holdings in both accounts?

I understand what happens in terms of tax, as mentioned in [this post](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/158104/brokerage-account-vs-roth-ira). Does the individual brokerage account not being tax-free change an individual's investment strategy?

Comment: Interesting question! I'm honestly not sure if it makes more sense to push the Roth farther toward growth assets than the non-tax-sheltered investments, or farther toward assets which pay dividends that you explicitly reinvest, or if it makes no difference. Or apply the same question to traditional, or to all three. I've been ignoring it, but it feels like there might be some minor tax optimization, or at least tax scheduling, opportunities here. But I'm not sure if that what you are asking or if I should open a new Question for this one.